# How do i get variable data from outside a callback function scope?

Tags: jquery, callback, ion-range-slider

I'm trying to get the values of the current position of the range slider, so as to put in an object for my ajax request...

```
let minPrice;
let maxPrice;
$('.range-slider').on('start', function(input) {
   minPrice = input.from;
   maxPrice = input.to;         
});       
console.log(minPrice,maxPrice);
```

Comment: The simple answer is, you don't. The event listener in your code is an _asynchronous_ function. Try this: change your current `console.log` to `console.log('outside')` and add a `console.log('inside')` inside the callback function (either above or below the two assignments). Now load your page. You will see that the `outside` message is logged immediately. Then start dragging the slider and you will see the 'inside' message.

Comment: To fix this, whatever action you need to take when the user starts dragging the slider, you need to put that _inside_ the callback, or in another function that you _call from_ the callback.

Comment: And here is some reading on the topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+asynchronous+callback